# How to use regex to check a sequence of 21 characters?

Tags: python, regex

I have a complex *product code* to validate in Python code as below:

**A8F30-ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM** - for each letter I have around 7 different possibilities. Example:

1º (A) Character - Fix, all the time will be A;

2º (8) Character - Flexible, can be number 5 or 8 only;

3º (F) Character - Flexible, can be string F or M or G or C only;

4º (3) Character - Flexible, can be number 2 or 3 only;

5º (0) Character - Flexible, can be number 0 or 2 only;

6º (-) Character - FIX;

7º to 21º - Character - Flexible, can be string A or B or C or D or E or F or G;

How can I define the RegEx 'Regular Expression' to cover this validation code?

Comment: protip, you don't need a regex for this. Anyway, what did you try? where did you get stuck?

Comment: Your example code does not match your description

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I see you've marked this as a duplicate of that reference again `Reference - What does this regex mean?` SI don't see a regex in the OP's question. To help us all out, can you explain what the duplicate is as it relates to this question ?

Comment: Since you have a bunch of `can be one of these` at the end, the common regex is `A[58][FMGC][23][02][-A-M]{16}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/gRgRbN/1) the solution :

```
(A)(5|8)(F|M|G|C)(2|3)(0|2)((-)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G){4,4}){3,3}
```

Comment: Thanks @L. Quastana, It is what I need, simple but I got many error before.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
\bA[58][FMGC][23][02](?:-[ABCDEFG]{4}){3}\b
```

or, a bit shorter:

```
\bA[58][FMGC][23][02](?:-[A-G]{4}){3}\b
```

Since your example and description don't match, I assumed you really wanted three groups of `-AAAA` at the end where `A` could be in the set of `[A-G]`.

But in your example, you show the last to be a group of five, and also letters that are not in `[A-G]`.

The regex is easily modified when you clarify what you really want.